# Single HTML link across multiple, non-contiguous words/lines?

Tags: html, css, hover

Given a list with various items set as links:

```
<ol>
 <li> <a href="http://linkA.com"> one </li>
 <li> two </a> </li>
 <li> <a href="http://linkB.com"> three </a> </li>
 <li> four </li>
 <li> <a href="http://linkB.com"> five </a> </li>
 <li> six </li>
</ol>
```

And CSS to highlight links like this:

```
a:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Is there a way to make *multiple items* highlight if *any individual item* is hovered?

And in particular, can I make *non-contiguous* elements highlight together?

For instance, item `one` and `two` above should both highlight in yellow, with *either* is hovered over.  And same with item `three` and `five` above?

Comment: It is obviously not valid. Tags have to be closed in the counter order the way they have been opened. What you intend to do is possible with JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done with CSS ***only*** if the links were *sibling* elements, using the `~` operator.

```css
.link_a:hover, .link_a:hover ~ .link_a { background: #FF0; }
.link_b:hover, .link_b:hover ~ .link_b { background: #FF0; }
```

```html
<p>
  <a class="link_a" href="http://linkA.com">one</a><br>
  <a class="link_a" href="http://linkA.com">two</a><br>
  <a class="link_b" href="http://linkB.com">three</a><br>
  four<br>
  <a class="link_b" href="http://linkB.com">five</a><br>
  six
</p>
```

But the HTML provided by OP doesn't fit this format and so JavaScript is currently the only option for this type of functionality.

I have an example that doesn't use additional classes per link but rather compares the `href` attribute to determine if two links go to the same place (*which seems to fit what OP is trying to achieve*).

```js
document.querySelectorAll("a").forEach(a => {
  a.addEventListener("mouseover", e => {
    document.querySelectorAll("a").forEach(b => {
      if(b.href == e.target.href) b.classList.add("hovered");
    });
  });
  a.addEventListener("mouseout", e => {
    document.querySelectorAll("a").forEach(b => {
      if(b.href == e.target.href) b.classList.remove("hovered");
    });
  });
})
```

```css
.hovered { background: #FF0; }
```

```html
<ol>
  <li><a href="http://linkA.com">one</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://linkA.com">two</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://linkB.com">three</a></li>
  <li>four</li>
  <li><a href="http://linkB.com">five</a></li>
  <li>six</li>
</ol>
```

**NOTE** *I understand looping through all links on an event listener can impact performance, but it is dependent on the specific page/case. Given a relatively small number of links there should not be any noticeable impact to performance. However on a page with a large number of links, there may be issues.*

Comment: just  need to use `querySelectorAll` and select the 2 links (which is quite small) and then use `forEach` as the iteration method. Then the performance impact literally is not existing even on longer lists.

Comment: Coming back to this... I love your CSS solution (would rather avoid JS) and I can restructure the content such that all links are siblings.... however, the `~` selector only highlights _subsequent_ elements... so hovering on "three" highlights three and five, but hovering on five only highlights five.   -- Do you know of a way to use CSS to highlight *all* siblings, before or after the item being hovered?

Answer (score 0):

Done with `JavaScript`

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".hover-a").forEach(element=>{
  element.addEventListener("mouseenter", ()=>{
    document.querySelectorAll(".hover-a").forEach(element=>{
      element.classList.add("is-hovered")
    })
  })
  element.addEventListener("mouseleave", ()=>{
    document.querySelectorAll(".hover-a").forEach(element=>{
      element.classList.remove("is-hovered")
    })
  })
})

document.querySelectorAll(".hover-b").forEach(element=>{
  element.addEventListener("mouseenter", ()=>{
    document.querySelectorAll(".hover-b").forEach(element=>{
      element.classList.add("is-hovered")
    })
  })
  element.addEventListener("mouseleave", ()=>{
    document.querySelectorAll(".hover-b").forEach(element=>{
      element.classList.remove("is-hovered")
    })
  })
})
```

```css
a:hover, .is-hovered {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<ol>
 <li class="hover-a"> <a href="http://linkA.com"> one </a> </li>
 <li class="hover-a"> <a href="http://linkA.com"> two </a> </li>
 <li class="hover-b"> <a href="http://linkB.com"> three </a> </li>
 <li> four </li>
 <li class="hover-b"> <a href="http://linkB.com"> five </a> </li>
 <li> six </li>
</ol>
```